# Vector with unknown length in spss

Tags: vector, syntax, spss

I want to find the mean of some variable which satisfy some attribute properties.

For example, let `att1` and `att2` be two variable attributes. I want to create a variable that is the average of the variables for which both `att1=3` and `att2=3`.

The problem with the syntax below is that I don't know the length of the vector `vec` and therefore *I cannot create it without specifying its length.*

```
COMPUTE newvar = MEAN(vec).
EXECUTE
```

Comment: please add more information about the vector and how it is formed in the first place, this should help finding a solution or a workaround.